# jQuery UI theme selector, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, themes

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5, visual studio 2013. I have downloaded the JQuery-ui theme and it is now being applied to my web project. Can I have more than one theme downloaded and allow user to select them on fly, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not? Check the [Super-Theme-Switcher](https://github.com/harborhoffer/Super-Theme-Switcher) and its demo [here](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/188460/themeswitcher/sample.htm).